# Is it 'rerun' or 're-run'?

Tags: word-usage

If you want to run a program you have previously, do you say "rerun" or "re-run"?

Comment: If you're **saying** it then there is no difference!

Comment: Use 'rerun' when referring to an action yet to take place.

Answer (score 10):

As seen in the *Oxford Dictionary of English*, the correct spelling is *rerun*:

> **rerun**
>
> ▸ verb /riːˈrʌn/
>   (reruns, rerunning; past reran; past participle rerun)
>   [with obj.] show, stage, or perform again:
>   she can stop the video and rerun a short sequence.
>
> ▸ noun /ˈriːrʌn/ an event or programme which is run again:
>   the World Cup rerun.

Answer (score 2):

It is **rerun**.

A quick search assured me that rerun is the correct spelling. I remembered this also as an option in a debug program.